# Debian 9: su command not working

Tags: linux, debian, iso-image

I have just set up a new PC with a [fresh debian 9.0.1 iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/debian-live-9.0.1-amd64-gnome.iso). The system is running fine but the `su` command does not work.

```
user@debian:~$ su
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

I reinstall system several times and test all install options (graphical install, expert install, lvm, standart partition ...) but I always encounter this issue with the `su` command.

I am sure of my password, I choose `ben` as root password for testing purpose.
I am also sure of my keyboard layout.

I am totally blocked since the `sudo` command is not configured by default on debian 9.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 4):

Your root account might be locked. You can verify this via:

```
sudo passwd -S root
```

If in the output line `root` is followed by an `L`, the root account is locked.

You can set a new password for root via:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Afterwards, `su` should work.

Besides that, it is often recommended to use `sudo -i` or `sudo su` instead of `su`. For further information, have a look at the Debian Wiki: https://wiki.debian.org/sudo

Answer (score 2):

Had the same thing; solved it like this:

In your grub menu, select your Debian install and press 'e' to edit the kernel arguments.

Find the line starting with linux and add `init=/bin/bash` to the end of the line. Then start Debian with <kbd>F10</kbd>. You will see a terminal.

Mount the filesystem as read-write with:
`mount -o remount,rw /`

Change the password with the passwd command: 
`passwd root`

Answer (score 0):

When you exec `su` command you must provide the password of target user. In your case:

```
su
```

this is the root password. To exec the operation with your password you should use the command:

```
sudo su -
```

P.S. Use dash after `su` command to get the environment of target user

Comment: I provide the password of the root user, as explained root password is 'ben' for testing purpose.

Comment: @ben.IT, how did you enable root user, how did you set the password of root?

Comment: @ Romeo Ninov, the debian installer asks me for the root password during install. I have no doubt about this password.

Comment: @ben.IT, try to change it again (just in case) with `sudo passwd`

Comment: as explained: `user is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.`